# Comparing txt file to third column in a csv bash

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I am very new to programming and decided to learn bash as we deal with some log servers that are Linux/Unix based and so scripting is a bit easier.

I have a cvs file that is laid out as follows:

PC,user,file,path - all comma separated.

I have a white list of file names that are line separated. Some include spaces.

My goal is to compare the whitelist to column 3 of the csv file and output all lines that don't match. I have tried a while read loop with an if statement but cannot seem to get it to work. I have done a few awk one liners and actually got one from a past stackoverflow post that outputted the lines that matched the whitelist but I cannot seem to figure out how to reverse to the logic to get it to work. Code is below.

```
awk     'BEGIN{i=0}
       FNR==NR { a[i++]=$1; next }
        { for(j=0; j<i; j++)
            if(index($0,a[j]))
                {print $0;break}
        }' $whitelist $exestartup
```

I would like to stick to basic bash with no add-ons and not opposed to doing a loop/if statement instead of an awk one liner.

Sample input/output:

whitelist.txt

program.exe
super program.exe
possible-program.exe

exestartup.csv

Asset1,user1,potato.exe,c:\users\user1
Asset2,user2,program.exe,c:\users\user2
Asset3,user3,possible-program.exe,c:\users\user3
Asset4,user4,super program.exe,c:\users\user4

Output

Asset1,user1,potato.exe,c:\users\user1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
awk -F, 'FNR==NR{a[$1]; next} !($3 in a)' whitelist exestartup
```

set the field delimiter to comma.  Load all whitelist names and compare against $3 fields of the file, if not match; print.

If you post sample input and expected output you'll get more answers and perhaps better suggestions.

using your input files

```
$ awk -F, 'FNR==NR{a[$1]; next} !($3 in a)' whitelist.txt exestartup.csv

Asset1,user1,potato.exe,c:\users\user1
```

if your `awk` is broken and the field values are disjoint you can revert to `grep`

```
$ grep -vf whitelist.txt exestartup.csv

Asset1,user1,potato.exe,c:\users\user1
```

Comment: Worth mentioning that using `$1` in the `FNR==NR` block is correct only because of the use of `-F,`. Were that not there this would only assign the first whitespace-delimited field of each line in `whitelist` to `a`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! It appears that prints out almost the whole csv file. Updating original post with sample input/output.

Comment: So I have see that awk one liner before and have used it before and so tried it again and still not working with my .txt and .csv and so to make sure I was not going crazy, I wrote my sample input/output files as above and did in fact get the answer I needed. But it appears formatting or something is off within my whitelist and/or csv file. I retyped my whole whitelist.txt in nano just on the safe side and still just prints out the whole csv file. I am going insane >< lol

Comment: debug! best way to learn.  change to `FNR==NR{a[$1]; print FILENAME, $1; next} {print FILENAME, $3}'` to print what `awk` sees

Comment: I did just that and ya, it is will print everything in my whitelist and csv correctly in the debug but on the original awk, it just seems to ignore the whitelist.txt and just dumps the .csv as the output.

Comment: however there is no field level constraint in grep.

Answer (score 0):

Using `join`:

```
$ join -v 1 -t, -1 3 -2 1 -o 1.1,1.2,1.3,1.4 <(sort -t, -k3,3 exestartup.csv) <(sort whitelist.txt)
Asset1,user1,potato.exe,c:\users\user1
```

If the input files are already sorted on the matching key (they don't appear to be in your example), that could simply be:

```
$ join -v 1 -t, -1 3 -2 1 -o 1.1,1.2,1.3,1.4 exestartup.csv whitelist.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution uses only Bash 3 builtins:

```
IFS=$'\n' read -d '' -r -a whitefiles < whitelist.txt

while IFS= read -r csvline || [[ -n $csvline ]] ; do
    IFS=, read pc user file path <<< "$csvline"
    for wfile in "${whitefiles[@]}" ; do
        [[ $wfile == "$file" ]] && continue 2
    done
    printf '%s\n' "$csvline"
done < exestartup.csv
```

A much faster and cleaner solution can be implemented in Bash 4 because it's got associative arrays.